# GRUB not showing after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday, and after I shutdown my pc, I have found that GNU grub 2 menu is not showing at more, so there is completely no video signal until I booted into Ubuntu.

I've collected a lot of resources online and still not being able to enabling dual boot option.

Things I have tried:

1. Press and hold F11, ESC, Shift before on startup.
2. Using boot-repair to automatically repairs my grub.
3. Manually set my default GRUB to windows.
4. Set my default GRUB to windows in boot-repair software.
5. I am not sure if this piece of info is helpful, I've managed to change boot manager back to windows bootmgr, but even windows boot manager is not showing during boot, I think this might not be a problem related to ubuntu anymore. But I would still love to hear from people who have encountered same problems. Thanks!

None of these actually helped my to get the GRUB screen showing, so after I starts my pc, the black screen continues until I see Ubuntu.

Could anyone share some thoughts about the problem? What should I do to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: @karel, I have tried the top few most voted solutions, not having an effect for me...

Comment: Yeah in case it is not clear, I've spent some time in the page you mentioned before I posted the question, but Rescatux is an option I have not tried. I will work on it now.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this personally with my laptop. It turned out my laptop didn't support graphical GRUB terminal. Simply set `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in the grub file at `/etc/default/grub` and this should fix the problem.